# Aggregating multiple matches before ordering results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an Activity node `(a)` that refers to `(:Something)` which can be matched by a direct `:LIKE` relationship to `:User 'me'` **OR** a `:LIKE` relationship by a `:FRIEND`.

The first relationship can be described as:

```
MATCH (a)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:LIKE]-(:User {user: 'me'})
```

While the second relationship can be described as:

```
MATCH (a)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:LIKE]-(:User)<-[:FRIEND]-(:User {user: 'me'})
```

How would I go about grouping all of the different activity nodes `(a)` so that I can sort the full list by timestamps?  It would look something like:

```
MATCH
  (a)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:LIKE]-(:User {user: 'me'})
OR
  (a)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:LIKE]-(:User)<-[:FRIEND]-(:User {user: 'me'})
RETURN a
ORDER BY a.ts DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use [the variable-length pattern matching](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength):

```
// u = node "me" or the node "friend"
MATCH
  (:User {user: 'me'})-[:FRIEND*0..1]->(u:User)
MATCH
  (a)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:LIKE]-(u)
RETURN DISTINCT a 
ORDER BY a.ts DESC
```

**Update**: If the queries are completely different, then you can collect the result of the first query, then the result of the second query, sum up and unwind:

```
MATCH 
  (a1)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:OWN]-(:User {user: 'me'})
WITH
  collect(DISTINCT a1) AS ac1
MATCH 
  (a2)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:INCLUDES]-(:SomethingElse)<-[:LIKE]-(:User {user: 'me'})
WITH
  ac1, collect(DISTINCT a2) AS ac2 
UNWIND 
  ac1 + ac2 AS a
RETURN DISTINCT a
ORDER BY a.ts DESC
```

Comment: What if my MATCH statements were less similar, like
`MATCH (a)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:OWN]-(:User {user: 'me'}) RETURN a` + 
`MATCH (a)-[:REF]->(:Something)<-[:INCLUDES]-(:SomethingElse)<-[:LIKE]-(:User {user: 'me'}) RETURN a` then
`ORDER BY a.ts DESC`.
Both `MATCH` statements returns a different set of results, where I'm really interested in grouping the results and sorting everything by timestamp. In practice, I'd like to aggregate several queries with `(a:Activity)` nodes which vastly different graph traversals between queries.

Comment: if my second MATCH queries returns 0 results, I'm seemingly getting no results for the final aggregated result (where I'd like to get the full set.)

Comment: Try `optional match` - https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/optional-match/

Comment: Using OPTIONAL MATCH, it seems to disregard that I'm only interested in a:Activity nodes that :REF to `:Something` -- I'm getting all kinds of different type referrals instead of just those pertaining to `:Something`.